# How to access EditText placed in a custom layout made for an AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I have made a custom layout for `AlertDialog` in which there is an `EditText`.

On click of a button I want to check whether this edittext is empty or filled so that I can carry on further operations.

Here is xml code for custom layout for AlertDialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="type here"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's what I'm doing with java code:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUpActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Choose a unique username");
            builder.setView(R.layout.choose_unique_name_dialog);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    if (uniqueUserName.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                .make(coordinatorLayout, "Please choose a unique username", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snackbar.show();
                    } else {
                        signingUpMethod();
                    }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
```

So, I want to know **how to access this `EditText` from my `MainActivity`?**

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inflate the layout you're setting to your alertDialog like this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View alertDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout,null);
```

Access your EditText like this

```
EditText editText = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.id);
```

Comment: this worked for me, but the problem is that the behaviour which should be shown only when edittext is empty is also getting shown when there is some text in it. Why so?

Comment: You mean to say you want to show this alertDialog only on some condition?

Comment: please see the edited question... I'm doing the checking after positivebutton being clicked. if the edittext is empty, a snackbar is shown and if it isn't, a method is executed but in either conditions the snackbar is getting shown.

Comment: Probably it has to do something with your logic. Try printing your edittext value on click of your continue button. Put a `Log` message or may be you have to debug.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code,

**make it  as `public` `static` method and you can access from Any other activity**

Store `edittext` value in some **static** variable and access from another class.

Comment: didt you find this helpful?@Hammad Nasir

Comment: Than you should try. This is easy way to access edittext value.

Comment: hey, SripadRaj's answer helped me but I'm facing this problem still. Please have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490382/how-to-access-edittext-placed-in-a-custom-layout-made-for-an-alertdialog/39490547?noredirect=1#comment66299220_39490535